# Split map to regions of property prices

Tags: algorithm, region

I have a collection of points with weights as property price. I need to split map to the regions of property prices. As so the sibling regions with the close price should be merge. Something like Voronoi Diagram but with region merging. Could you suggest me some good algorithms. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're looking for the keyword `clustering`, look up k-means and expectation maximisation using gaussian mixture models and go from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use k-means clustering to find the boundaries of the given dataset. Here's a good link for starters https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-means-clustering-introduction/